# (boundary conditions) Interface between two lossless media

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge, boundary-conditions

I'm wondering why there's usually no free charges nor free currents in the interface between two lossless media? 
no free current "I guess" is due to the insulating nature of a lossless media but why no free charges ?

thanx in advance :)

Comment: There can be plenty of free charges. Why do you think they couldn't be any?